# Python ctypes cannot get long string value returned from .so file

Tags: python, c

I am learning C and trying to import a .so into my python file for higher performance by using a python package ctypes. So everything going well until I had a hard time when trying to get a string returned from .so file.

C code:

```
char *convert_to_16(char *characters, int n){

    char sub_buffer[3];
    char code[3];
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(characters) * 2);
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        strncpy(code, characters+i, 1);
        sprintf(sub_buffer, "%x", *code);
        strncat(buffer, sub_buffer, 2);
    } 
    return buffer;
}

// main() only for test
int main(){
    char param[] = "ABCDEFGHTUIKLL";
    printf("%s\n", param);
    int length = strlen(param);
    printf("%s\n", convert_to_16(param, length));
}
```

It runs well with output:

> > 41424344454647485455494b4c4c

Python code :

```
c_convert_to_16 = ctypes.CDLL('./convert_to_16.so').convert_to_16
c_convert_to_16.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

a_string = "ABCDEFGHTUIKLL"
new_16base_string = c_convert_to_16(a_string, len(a_string))
print new_16base_string
```

It runs but only returns two characters:

> > 41

I read the official doc and set restype as ctypes.c_char_p, and try to set it to other values. But it seems it's the only option, just oddly only two characters were returned.

Is it the problem of my ctypes configuration or my C wasn't written correctly?
Many thanks.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks! I should have assigned more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about ctypes in python but you should create your string like that `c_char_p("ABCDEFGHTUIKLL")`.

And maybe tell what argument take your function `c_convert_to_16.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_size_t]`

This will fix your undefined behavior in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convert_to_16(char const *array, size_t const len);

char *convert_to_16(char const *array, size_t const len) {
  size_t const len_buffer = len * 2 + 1;
  char *buffer = malloc(len_buffer);
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t used = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (len_buffer < used || len_buffer - used < 3) {
      free(buffer);
      return NULL;
    }
    int ret = snprintf(buffer + used, 3, "%.2x", (unsigned char)array[i]);
    if (ret != 2) {
      free(buffer);
      return NULL;
    }
    used += 2;
  }
  return buffer;
}

int main(void) {
  char const param[] = "ABCDEFGHTUIKLL";
  printf("%s\n", param);
  char *ret = convert_to_16(param, sizeof param - 1);
  if (ret != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", ret);
  }
  free(ret);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your c codes show me a very professional way! I finally found a way to fix this bug, it caused by my ctypes configuration. And setting c_char_p to c_convert_to_16.argtypes does work, many thanks.