# Unsigned Char Concat In C

Tags: c, char, unsigned-char

im trying to convert a string message to hex value in C.

For example if i have a message like "abc" i want to have it by 162636 etc. My code is below. In this code, i have to do some concat operation to store them all but now i can store only 36. How can i store them?

```
unsigned char swapNibbles(char x)
{
    return ( (x & 0x0F)<<4 | (x & 0xF0)>>4 );
}

void encode(char *message, char password[40]) {
    unsigned char *reversedInput = malloc(strlen(message));


    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(message); ++i) {
        reversedInput=swapNibbles(message[i]);
    }
    printf("%2x TERS ",reversedInput);
    //unsigned char *bitwiseMessage = (unsigned char*)message;
    //printf("DÜZ %s\n",bitwiseMessage);
    //printf("TERS %u\n", swapNibbles(bitwiseMessage));
}
```

Comment: This answer provide a way to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/41356195/7076153

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh, if i dont cast it, i will get segmentation fault

Comment: @Berkin That's one more reason for not to cast. Did you include `stdlib.h`?

Comment: Did the compiler not provide warnings?

Comment: To expand what @PaulHankin said, if yes, why you chose to ignore them?

Comment: `malloc(strlen(...))` is (almost always) wrong.

Comment: `unsigned char *reversedInput = (unsigned char*)malloc(strlen(message));` You don't need malloc  --> `unsigned char reversedInput;`

Comment: unsigned char *reversedInput = malloc((unsigned char*) strlen(message));
I convert it to this. Also my reversed input is not a single byte. Its more than 1 @BLUEPIXY

Comment: WTF are you doing? Casting `strlen()` to a pointer and passing it to `malloc`?! Your compiler should be screaming at you for that.

Comment: `printf("%02x",reversedInput);` move into for-loop.

Comment: Then your compiler should be complaining about `reversedInput=swapNibbles(message[i]);` because you're assigning a char (which is an integer) to a pointer.

Comment: what's "concation"? And put code inside backticks `\`like this\`` to make it readable

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, yeah its right but i need to store them all. How can i store them

Comment: @melpomene, should i cast it to (unsigned char) ? Im not good at in C. Thanks

Comment: You do not need to store it unless you simply display it and use it elsewhere.

Comment: No, you should read a basic C tutorial or take a class or something. You have no idea what you're doing and your idea of problem solving is sprinkling random casts over the code. Casts aren't magic: They just tell the compiler to shut up; they don't fix problems.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, i need it because i need whole string. For example if i have abc i need 616263

Comment: So `swapNibbles` is not necessary.

Comment: Seriously? Ok im changing my answer. I need to store "whole" of the message. If i have "abc" it means i need "162636". Whole of 162636, not 16,26,36.

Comment: I just realized `swapNibbles` has nothing to do with the problem you claim you're trying to solve. Did you just copy/paste that from somewhere else into your program?

Comment: Im using it to change A-61 to 16. After change it to 16, i have to store them into reversedInput. And it goes like this. Swap nibbles does this

Comment: you have been saying "i need 616263"  for a long time.

Comment: It was an example. My function does this convert. Its not a problem. My problem is just stroing them all, together

Comment: It was totally wrong as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit***

My solution for hex-encoding:  [**IDEOne**](http://ideone.com/Ph0H4p)

---

If you want your text to be hex-encoded, you will have to allocate ***twice*** as much space as the original message:

```
"abc" (3 bytes) ==> "616263" (6 bytes)
```

So you will need:

```
unsigned char *reversedInput = malloc(2*strlen(message)+1);  // +1 for the final NULL-terminator
```

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

char* HexEncode(char* txt)
{
    char* hexTxt = calloc(2*strlen(txt)+1,1);
    for(char* p=hexTxt; *txt; p+=2)
    {
        sprintf(p, "%02x", *txt++);
    }
    return hexTxt;
}

int main() {
    char* hexText = HexEncode("Hello World");
    printf("Hexed is %s\n", hexText);
    free(hexText);

    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
Hexed is 48656c6c6f20576f726c64
```

Comment: Thank you :) I chaned it

Comment: Note: If the purpose is to stock character `reversedInput` should be of type `char *`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Thanks alot :) That is what i needed

Comment: `sprintf(p, "%0x", *txt);` --> `sprintf(p, "%0x", (unsigned char)*txt);`

Comment: Only matters when the MSB is on.  That should not happen in 7-bit ascii.

Comment: `'o'` ==> `6f` ==> `swapNibbles` ==> `f6`

Comment: OP is very confused on that point:  Says they want hex-encoding, then starts swapping nibbles for no reason.  My answer focuses ONLY on the hex-encoding part.  If they want to swap nibbles that is a separate problem.

Comment: Try `HexEncode("Hello\tWorld")` --> `"48656c6c6f9"`.    `sprintf(p, "%0x", *txt++);` may only print 1 character.  Suggest `sprintf(p, "%02x", *txt++);`